# Is there a term for a values within a range?

Tags: statistics, terminology

I've learned that a range is the difference between the maximum and minimum values, but is there a term for the fraction which describes a value within that range?

Like if the range were between 40 and 90, the value 60 would be 2/5...

Maybe just call it "percent of range?"

Related: what about a term for the value minus the minimum? The value 60 would have a (utility?) of 20 in the above scenario.

Finally, suppose you needed to apply a percent to a range to obtain the corresponding value, where 0.4 * range returns 60. Is there a term for this sort of operation?

Sorry, I don't have a stats text book and I don't know the terms I need to research it myself...

Comment: I'm curious what this has to do with statistics. I would just say that 60 is equal to 40 plus 2/5 times the distance between 90 and 40, rather, $60 = 40+ \frac{2}{5}(90-40)$. Similarly, I would simply say that 60 is greater than 40, and the difference between them is 20, i.e., $60-40=20.$

Comment: What you're doing, it seems, is trying to find new names for arithmetic operations. With regard to the last thing, I would say $a + 0.4x = 60$ where $x=b-a$ for some real numbers $a<b$, e.g. $a=40$ and $b=90$ (sorry I keep catching typos).

Comment: There is a concept called _percentiles_ that is quite important in statistics (also the related terms _median,_ _quartiles,_ and _quintiles_), but it is quite a bit different from what you are asking for. The range is usually not as useful AFAIK; it is very sensitive to _outliers._